# How do I generate functions from the struct definitions?

Tags: c, parsing, code-generation, deserialization

I'm writing a library for deserializing data. I've got struct definitions like:

```
#ifndef SEARCHRESULTS_H
#define SEARCHRESULTS_H

typedef struct {
    char *url;
} SearchResult;

typedef struct {
    int count;
    SearchResult *searchResults;
} SearchResults;

#endif
```

Since C lacks reflection, all the functions have to be written manually, but I believe there should be a nice way to parse the headers, find the `struct` names and fields, and generate the functions (pseudo-C):

```
#include "SearchResults.h"
#include "pdata_serialization.h"

void SearchResult_parse(pdata *data, SearchResult *obj) {
    obj->url = strdup(data->values["url"]);
}

void SearchResult_free(SearchResult *obj) {
    free(obj->url);
    free(obj);
}

void SearchResults_parse(pdata *data, SearchResults *obj) {
    obj->count = data->values["count"];
    obj->searchResults = malloc(sizeof(SearchResult) * obj->count);
    for (int i = 0; i < obj->count; i++)
        SearchResult_parse(data->values["searchResults"][i], &obj->searchResults[i]);
}

void SearchResults_free(SearchResults *obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < obj->count; i++)
        SearchResult_free(&obj->searchResults[i]);
    free(obj);
}
```

I'm not looking for a complete solution, but a sane and minimal idea and a small example.

Comment: It's possible that [*X macros*](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) will come to the rescue here.

Comment: Historically this kind of problem has been solved by external tools that take a different format for input and generate the structs and functions for serializing and deserializing. You could probably solve it with creative abuse of the preprocessor, but that leads quickly to madness.

Comment: What's this pdata thingie here? For me it looks like you want an associative array (map) instead of a struct? What should happen in case a "values" field 'count' does not exist?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, thanks! Reading the article and trying to use them now.

Comment: @Art, I'm open to external tools which are relatively small. In fact, I've spend few hours reading about `awk` and `sed`, but I failed to write anything useful.

Comment: @user2018448: TBH, I haven't looked at your code properly.  X macros may or may not be sufficient here.  And it's also possible that an external tool might be a cleaner solution.  But it's well worth looking at them.

Comment: @junix, the `pdata` is just an imaginary interface to demonstrate the main idea. In the real code I am deserializing JSON data using the [json-parser](https://github.com/udp/json-parser). That is, I am looping over the parsed fields and `strcmp`ing their names with known ones.

Comment: @user2018448 Ok, then I'm afraid the only thing you can do here is providing sort of a lookup function to go through the parsed fields I think (as I wrote above: something map like). This is because the field names of the struct are not available anymore at runtime. This is all translated to offsets and memory addresses.

Comment: @junix, yes, but the headers already contain field names! I'm just looking for a way to generate the functions from the headers, so I wouldn't have to handcraft them. Still, thanks for the lookup function hint, it could be possible to combine this with the X macros solution provided by Oli Charlesworth.

Comment: @user2018448 So you don't create the attribute fields dynamically depending on the content of your JSON object?

Comment: @junix, yes, exactly - the fields of each `struct` are known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with [GNU Autogen](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/manual/autogen.html). I converted my headers into definition files, one per struct:

```
// SearchResult.def
AutoGen Definitions struct;
struct = {
    type = "char *";
    name = "url";
};

// SearchResults.def
AutoGen Definitions struct;
struct = {
    type = "SearchResult *";
    name = "searchResults";
};
```

and wrote the following not-so-pretty template:

```
[= AutoGen5 Template h c =][=
    (define model (string-substitute (def-file) ".def" ""))
=][=
    CASE (suffix)
=][=
    == h
=][=
    (make-header-guard "")
=]

typedef struct _[= (. model) =] {[=
    FOR struct =]
    [=
        (get "type")
    =][=
        (get "name")
    =];[=
        IF (and (*== (get "type") "*") (not (== (get "type") "char *"))) =]
    size_t [= (get "name") =]Count;[=
        ENDIF =][=
    ENDFOR struct
=]
} [= (. model) =];

#endif /* [= (. header-guard) =] */
[=
    == c
=]#include "[= (. header-file) =]"
#include "pdata_serialization.h"

void [= (. model) =]_parse(pdata *data, [= (. model) =] *obj) {[=
    FOR struct =][=
        IF (== (get "type") "char *")
    =]
    obj->[= (get "name") =] = strdup(data->values["[= (get "name") =]"]);[=
        ELIF (*== (get "type") "*")
    =]
    obj->[= (get "name") =]Count = data->values["[= (get "name") =]Count"];
    obj->[= (get "name") =] = malloc(sizeof([= (string-substitute (get "type") " *" "") =]) * obj->[= (get "name") =]Count);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj->[= (get "name") =]Count; i++)
        [= (string-substitute (get "type") " *" "") =]_parse(data->values["[= (get "name") =]"][i], &obj->[= (get "name") =][i]);[=
        ENDIF
    =][=
    ENDFOR struct
=]
}

void [= (. model) =]_free([= (. model) =] *obj) {[=
    FOR struct =][=
        IF (== (get "type") "char *")
    =]
    free(obj->[= (get "name") =]);[=
        ELIF (*== (get "type") "*")
    =]
    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj->[= (get "name") =]Count; i++)
        [= (string-substitute (get "type") " *" "") =]_free(&obj->[= (get "name") =][i]);
    free(obj->[= (get "name") =]);[=
        ENDIF
    =][=
    ENDFOR struct
=]
    free(obj);
}
[= ESAC =]
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend storing the parsed data as key-value pairs in a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) allowing you to lookup entities.

Of course you have to take measures for cases where the attributes asked for are not available (e.g. the url attribute is missing). Depending on how you store the information in the hash table, there is also a question of type safety. But maybe it's worth to store the key-value pairs as strings and convert them if needed to numbers or whatever.